# Trouble debugging ImportAblock: TPage Error

Tags: delphi, debugging

We have had reports of the below error given at seemingly random intervals (reported every week or so by one or two users only) and are unable to debug as we cannot reproduce at all (have been trying for a long time). Is anyone able to shed some light on steps we can take using Delphi XE7 to reproduce or debug this error further?

ImportAblock: TPage

Comment: Are you sure `ImportAblock: TPage` is the error message? It looks more like a declaration of a variable `ImportAblock` of type `TPage` to me.

Comment: Is this really all information you have? With such few information nobody will be able to help you.